# Which legendary skins have unique voice lines and unique visual abilities?

Tags: overwatch

For some legendary skins, it appears that they give the hero both unique visuals and unique voice lines.

Some legendary skins I know off the top of my head that have different voice lines:

- Mercy Imp or Devil, upon reviving she says "*Heroes never die! ... for a price.*"
- Hanzo Okami or Lone Wolf

  - upon using Sonar he will sometimes say "*See through the Wolf's eyes*" instead of "*See through the Dragon's eyes*"
  - upon Ult he says "Ryuu ga waga teki kurai" or something like that, and instead of 2 dragons flying out, 2 wolves fly out in the same formation

Besides the actual skins of the guns and player models being changed, are there other legendary skins which affect the ability appearances or the voice lines? I got my hands on a Vishkar Symmetra but it seems that, besides the model and the weapon being changed, I have not seen any unique voice lines or even unique ability animations or appearance changes.

Comment: I can help out with one more, Mercy's Sigrun and Valkyrie skin have "_'Till Valhalla_" as ultimate voice line.

Comment: @Lunaetic Post it as an answer!

Comment: I didn't want to post it as answer because I don't know if that's the only different voice line there is, so it would just be a partial answer. Do you really think I should do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Junkrat:

- His Fool and Jester skins have unique voice lines on kills:

  - "*Why so serious?*"
- His Junkenstein skin has unique voice lines on casting his Ultimate:

  - (enemy) "*Get ready for a shock!*"
  - (friendly) "*Behold my latest creation!*"

#### Torbjorn:

- His Barbarossa and Blackbeard skins have unique voice lines on kills, such as:

  - "*Shiver me timbers!*" (on enemy kill)
  - "*Ahoy there!*" (when saying hello)
- His Chopper and Deadlock skins replace his Forge hammer with a Tire Iron.

#### Tracer:

- Her T.Racer skin has a unique voice line when switching to her and playing as her:

  - "*Here comes T. Racer!*
- Both T.Racer and Mach T. have the possibility to say a voice line after a kill:

  - "*Speed kills!*"
- Both Track & Field and Sprinter have the possibility to say a voice line after using rewind:

  - "*False start!*"

#### Hanzo:

- His Lone Wolf and Okami skins have both unique abilities animations and voice lines:

  - On his Sonar Arrow he says lines such as:
  - "*See through the wolf's eyes*"
  - "*The wolf marks its prey*"
  - On his Dragonstrike he gets a unique animation and a new voice line:
  - The two spiraling dragons are replaced with two spiraling wolves, howling as they fly through the air
  - "*The wolf hunts for its prey!*"
  - "*Ōkami yo waga teki wo kurae*!"

#### Mercy:

- Her Valkyrie and Sigrun skins give her unique voice lines on casting her Ultimate:

  - "*Till Valhalla*"
- Her Imp and Devil skins give her unique voice lines on casting her Ultimate:

  - "*Heroes never die.....for a price.*"
- Her Witch skin has a unique voice line on casting her Ultimate:

  - "*My servants never die!*"

Comment: Tracer's punk skins have a chance to say "Wanker" after a kill.

Comment: Might want to make this into a community wiki so that others can add new items as they arise

Answer (score 1):

upon respawn with D.va's scavenger or junker skins equipped she sometimes gives the voiceline "You hear me baby? Hold together."

Answer (score 0):

The Pirate Torbjorn skins, instead of his normal hello voice lines he will sometimes say "Ahoy There!" I think he has a few different callouts also.

Comment: Thanks for the info! If you'd like to take this answer to the next level, you might want to list all of the different callouts :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, with Hanzos' Lone wolf and Okami Skins, he has a voice line, "I choose you..Spirit Dragon" but with these skins, dragon is replaced with the word "wolf".

Answer (score -1):

Reaper will occasionally say "nevermore" on enemy elimination with the nevermore skin equipped

Answer (score -2):

With the Jester and Fool skins for junkrat upon death there is a cartoon spring sound affect that plays followed by a laugh

Comment: That's for Junkrat in general.

Answer (score -2):

Don't forget Widowmaker with her huntress/comtesse skins!

Answer (score -3):

They get pretty subtle with some of them. I can't remember the exact line, and I don't have a solid way to check, but on Volskaya, basic Lucio has a line where he says he wishes he brought his hockey gear. If you're wearing a hockey skin, he wonders if he can find a pick up game. I wouldn't be surprised if there's similar minor changes for every skin in the game, considering the wide variety of trigger conditions.